# TypeScript computer property name in type declaration, inconsistent compiler error

Tags: typescript

Given these types:

```
export type TSimpleFilterDict = { 
      [fieldName: string]:  (
            number | number[]  | string | boolean | null |  undefined 
       )
};

export interface IMultiFieldTextSearchSpec {
    fieldNames : string[];
    expression : string;
};
export type TMultiFieldTextSearch = {
    "$text" ?: IMultiFieldTextSearchSpec;
}

export type TFilterDict = TSimpleFilterDict | TMultiFieldTextSearch;
```

If I do something like this:

```
let filter : TFilterDict = {};
filter.is_active = true;
```

Then I get this compiler error:

```
[ts]
Property 'is_active' does not exist on type 'TFilterDict'.
  Property 'is_active' does not exist on type 'TSimpleFilterDict'. [2339]
```

However, if I do this

```
let filter : TSimpleFilterDict = {};
filter.is_active = true;
```

Then it seems to be fine and the compiler does not give me any errors.

Moreover, this is fine too:

```
  let filter: TSimpleFilterDict = {};
  filter.is_active = true;
  let filter2 : TFilterDict = filter;
```

Also, if I do this:

```
    let filter : TFilterDict = {};
    filter.$text = {
        fieldNames: ["name", "address"],
        expression: "dave"
    };
```

Then it is fine, no warnings at all.

I don't understand this. How is it possible that I can set any property on a variable that has type `TSimpleFilterDict`, but I cannot do the same on a variable that has type `TSimpleFilterDict | TMultiFieldTextSearch` ? This seems insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your "This is insane!", I would say,

> There's a fine line between genius and insanity. [Typescript has] erased this line.

If you start from the basics of how unions work, all the behavior is entierly expected.

A variable of a union type can be either member type in the union. Given this, we can only safely access properties common to **all** memebers of a union.

Let's look at the first two examples:

```
let filter : TFilterDict = {};
filter.is_active = true //error

let filter4 : TSimpleFilterDict = {};
filter4.is_active = true; // ok
```

In `filter4` we can assign `is_active`, because `TSimpleFilterDict` has an index signature so we can assign any property. We can't do the same to `filter` because while `TSimpleFilterDict` does have an index signature, `TMultiFieldTextSearch` only has one property (`$text`). So `is_active = true` only works if `filter` is actually a specific type in the union, but will not work for **any** type in the union and thus typescript raises an error.

The next example:

```
let filter3: TSimpleFilterDict = {};
filter3.is_active = true;
let filter2 : TFilterDict = filter3;
```

This one is allowed, as `filter3` (as above) has an index signature and the assignment is valid. `filter2` can be either `TSimpleFilterDict` or `TMultiFieldTextSearch` so we can assign a `TSimpleFilterDict` to it. After the assignment (barring control flow analysis) typescript will no longer know for sure if `filter2` is a `TSimpleFilterDict` or a `TMultiFieldTextSearch`, so `filter2.is_active = true;` would be invalid for the same reason we got the error in the first example.

The final example :

```
let filter5 : TFilterDict = {};
filter5.$text = {
    fieldNames: ["name", "address"],
    expression: "dave"
};
```

This is valid because `$text` is present on `TMultiFieldTextSearch` and since `TSimpleFilterDict` accessing it with `$text` is also valid. Since `filter5.$text = { ... }` is valid for any type in the union, the assignment is valid. (Although since the member is accessed on a union, its type will be `string | number | boolean | number[] | IMultiFieldTextSearchSpec` when you try to access it)

Comment: Okay, I was a fool What I needed was `export type TFilterDict = TSimpleFilterDict & TMultiFieldTextSearch` but I used `|` instead of `&`. I'm not sure why. :-)

Comment: @nagylzs it's easy to get the two confused